# JSON object looped multiple times

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I seem to have gotten myself stuck with the data passed by JSON. When I console log to see the data passed, the object are repeatedly passed and this is affecting my append output.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://howtodeployit.com/api/get_recent_posts",
            dataType: "json",
            jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); },
            complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); },
            success:function (data){
                $.each(data.posts, function(key, val) {
                console.log(data.posts);

                var result = $('<li/>').append([$("<h3>", {html: val.title}),$("<p>", {html: val.excerpt})]).wrapInner('<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>');

                $('#postlist').empty().append(result);
            });
```

As seen below, this is appearing multiple times but the expected output should just be one line of object.
[image]

Comment: You are printing your json itself instead of key for the key length times

Comment: I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNjX7/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to load jsonp, the dataType should be **jsonp**

Also I do think you are trying to loop over each post. But there would be only one result since you empty the container every time.

So instead of :

```
$('#postlist').empty().append(result);
```

Use

```
$('#postlist').append(result);
```

And did you miss a closing braces??

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://howtodeployit.com/api/get_recent_posts",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function () {
        // $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
    },
    complete: function () {
        //  $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.posts, function (key, val) {
            console.log(data.posts);

            var result = $('<li/>').append([$("<h3>", {
                html: val.title
            }), $("<p>", {
                html: val.excerpt
            })]).wrapInner('<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>');

            $('#postlist').append(result);

        });
    }
});
```

here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dcF9R/1/).

Comment: I didn't miss a closing brace, only posted a section of it. Will try your suggestion#

Comment: Not working as expected. See the output [here](http://howtodeployit.com/newdevotion/index.html). Its only showing one post but the console log still shows multiple objects

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data.posts, function(key, val) {
```

That is a loop. So, assuming that the data.posts is an array that has multiple objects, you will see this fired as many times as there are posts.

What are you hoping to see?

Also, loxxy is right, you're missing a closing brace so it's hard to know where you intend your loop function to actually end.

Comment: I am expecting to see just one single line "[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
 "

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover there are are 11 `posts` being returned in the `data`.  The loop runs as many times. Please see my edits... is it what you intend?

Comment: Sorry you are right, I removed the .empty and that seems to work as expected